# How to limit results through an association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope

I have a rating model which belongs to a user and would like to get only the ratings whose users are confirmed.

```
Rating.includes(:user).merge(User.where.not(confirmed_at: nil))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 5+ syntax:

```
Rating.joins(:user).where.not(user: { confirmed_at: nil })
```

Comment: Why did you get rid of includes? Just to have less code?

Comment: Rails < 5 and using `includes` for @Ursus sake `Rating.includes(:user).references(:user).where(User.arel_table[:confirmed_at].not_eq(nil))`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to.

```
Rating.joins(:user).merge(User.where.not(confirmed_at: nil))
```

Comment: Why did you get rid of includes? Just to have less code?

Comment: includes eager loads the association whereas joins is for inner join. In order to use includes you have to use the references(:user). You can use join or you can use includes(:user) with references(:user) in the query